# Change graph on multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two radio buttons. When I click on one radio button a graph will be shown and on the other radio button click, a different graph will be shown.

This is what I've tried. But it's not working:

```
<input type="radio" name="status" id="graph" value="graph" onclick="getValue('operatorgraph');" checked>View Graph for Revenue</input>
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="graph" value="graph" onclick="getValue('hitsgraph');">View Graph for Hits</input>
    {else}
    <input name="status" id="graph" type="hidden"></input> 
    <input name="status" id="report" type="hidden"></input>
    {/if}
   </ul>
   </div>
   <br/>

   <div class="grid_12"> 
   <div class="box"> 
   <div class="header"> 
   <div class="content" style="height: 550px;position:relative"> 
   <div style="height: 500px;" class="chart">
    <div id="chartdiv" align="center" style="position:static;border: 5px solid #3f4041">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var chart = new FusionCharts("chart/images/FCF_MSLine.swf", "ChartId", "850", "500");
            //chart.setDataURL("datemap.xml");
            chart.setDataXML("{$productXML}");
            chart.render("chartdiv");
        </script>
      </div>
    <div id="chartdiv2" align="center" style="position:static;border: 5px solid #3f4041">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var chart = new FusionCharts("chart/images/FCF_MSColumn2D.swf", "ChartId", "850", "500");
            //chart.setDataURL("datemap.xml");
            chart.setDataXML("{$productXML2}");
            chart.render("chartdiv2");  

        </script>
      </div>
```

Here's my getValue function:

```
function getValue(attr,step)
{
    if (document.getElementById('graph').checked) 
    {
        type = document.getElementById('graph').value;
    } 
    else if(document.getElementById('report').checked)
    {
        type = document.getElementById('report').value;
    }
    else
    {
        type = 'graph';
    }   

    month = document.getElementById('month').value;  
    Year = document.getElementById('year').value;

if(type == 'graph')
    {
else if(attr == 'operatorgraph')
        {
            var poststring = "event=owg&y="+Year+"&start="+start+"&end="+end;
            //alert (poststring);
            //return false;
            loadXMLDoc(poststring, onOperatorWiseGraph);
        }
        else if(attr == 'hitsgraph')
        {
            var poststring = "event=owg&y="+Year+"&start="+start+"&end="+end;
            //alert (poststring);
            //return false;
            loadXMLDoc(poststring, onOperatorWiseGraphHits);
        }
}
///////////////////////////////////

function onOperatorWiseGraph(response)
{
    //alert(response);
        //document.getElementById('app').value = '';
        var is_chrome = /chrome/i.test( navigator.userAgent );
        if(is_chrome == false)
        {
        var chart = new FusionCharts("chart/images/FCF_MSLine.swf", "ChartId", "840", "400");       
        }
        else
        {
        var chart = new FusionCharts("chart/images/FCF_MSLine.swf", "ChartId", "840", "400");   
        }       
    chart.setDataURL("appc.xml");
    chart.render("chartdiv");
}
function onOperatorWiseGraphHits(response)
{
    //alert(response);
        //document.getElementById('app').value = '';
        var is_chrome = /chrome/i.test( navigator.userAgent );
        if(is_chrome == false)
        {
        var chart = new FusionCharts("chart/images/FCF_MSColumn2D.swf", "ChartId", "840", "400");       
        }
        else
        {
        var chart = new FusionCharts("chart/images/FCF_MSColumn2D.swf", "ChartId", "840", "400");   
        }       
    chart.setDataURL("appc.xml");
    chart.render("chartdiv");
}
```

Please tell where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Where is your `getValue` function?

Comment: Au, I did not see first time, but your code is totally invalid. This is because id should always unique in html. If not, you will get back only always the last element with the same id. First fix that.